# My directory created on a LAMP don't work in a WAMP

Tags: php, wamp, lamp

I have created a website in a LAMP using Apache MySQL and PHPmyAdmin, I have migrated this website and is db to a similar configuration but and Windows. And my directory are all mucked up. from index I am able to access any file in root location but if it is in a folder I have to had a `../../html`where I previously had `../`I have a lot of folder and a lot of `header(Location: ../whatever)` using them. How can I fix the directory ?

This is my root in var/www/ :
[image: root folder]
And this is inside the html folder (var/www/html) :
[image: html folder]

Comment: So did the root directory of the webserver change under windows?

Comment: There's a moral to this story...!

Comment: the root directory for windows is c:/wamp64/www

Comment: And it was what under linux?

Comment: Problem solved, files and folder must be directly in root in the WAMP